# Distributing iPhone apps under Enterprise program

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to figure out more details on how apps are distributed to users when under the Enterprise developer program. The [Enterprise Deployment Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en%5FUS/Enterprise%5FDeployment%5FGuide.pdf) states:

> If you develop an application that you want to distribute yourself, it must be digitally signed with a certificate issued by Apple. You must also provide your users with a distribution provisioning profile that allows their device to use the application.

What I want to know is how is the provisioning profile is created so that a specific device is allowed to use the app? Is this done by adding device UDIDs into the profile as per the standard developer program? Or some other means?

Answer (score 1):

Provisioning profiles are managed thanks a website provided by Apple. It will be possible to generate and download Provisioning profiles from this website.

Then, if you sign an application with the Enterprise program licence, you will be able to install it on any device. You just have to send to the user your application and the provisioning profile.

Regards,

Comment: So, doesn't this mean I could then sell my application outside the AppStore? I could make it available on my website and charge users to get access to a download link?

Comment: yes.. but only those people enrolled in the enterprise system will be able to buy it.

Comment: What? I don't follow. Surely I wouldn't expect all 500+ of my employees to be enrolled in the enterprise system? Or is that how it works? Are they enrolled by UDID?

Comment: Only the employer is enrolled, but each device that you want to deploy your enterprise app to have to be provisioned by the business

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'm being clear...what I want to is, does each device that this will be deployed to need to have it's UDID manually added to a provisioning profile?

Comment: to distribute via Enterprise Program no need to add any UDID for the provisioning profile. but make sure that enterprise distribution is only for the internal distribution of any organization.